# Only bottom part of image boarder is shown

Tags: html, css, image, border

Hello guys I'm doing a CSS/HTML course at the moment and I have to assign a border to images on my website. 
1. I gave the images a class:

```
 <a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elefanten" 
    target="_blank" 
    class="images>
    <img src="elefant.jpg" alt="Elefant">
```

2. In my CSS file I used following code to assign the border:

   .images 
   {

   ```
           border-left: 10px solid red;
           border-top: 10px solid red;
           border-bottom: 10px solid red;
           border-right: 10px solid red;
       }
   ```

Should be very easy code but the in Chrome it doesnt really seem to work correctly. Here a screenshot  :

https://snipboard.io/VAipY8.jpg

This is probably a very beginner thing but I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: In the actual file I didnt forget the closing tag of class= "images" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make the image a clickable link you should wrap it in between the `<a>` tag

```
<a href = " "><img src = " "></a>
```

And to add border to the image you should give class to the `<img>` tag not to the `<a>` tag.
Currently you are applying border to the link inside the `<a>` tag.

Comment: You are right. In the actual file it's correct though :D

Comment: Thanks. That I assigned the class to <a> and not to the image directly was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing / tag in the img tag. and the closing " in the class attribute. and the closing tag for the anchor tag. Write your code like this:

```
<a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elefanten" 
    target="_blank" 
    class="images" >    
    <img src="elefant.jpg" alt="Elefant" class="elephantImg" />
</a>
```

Change the css as follows:

```
img {

    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 10px solid red;
}
```

You can use this if you decide not to use the class attribute on the elephant image otherwise, if you decide to use the elephantImg class attribute use this css:

```
.elephantImg{

        border-left: 10px solid red;
        border-top: 10px solid red;
        border-bottom: 10px solid red;
        border-right: 10px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: You are right. In the actual file it's correct though :D